# Pass SQL parameter value to select xml data

Tags: sql, xml

**Code:**

```
DECLARE @dataxml XML = CONVERT(xml ,'<Parentnode><childnode><id>1</id></childnode></Parentnode>')

DECLARE @childnode  VARCHAR(50) 
SET @childnode = (SELECT DISTINCT 
                      r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as t 
                  FROM @dataxml.nodes('//Parentnode/*') AS records(r))

SELECT @childnode

SELECT
   t.value('id[1]', 'int') AS id 
FROM
   @dataxml.nodes('/Parentnode/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@childnode")]/*') AS XD(t)
```

Output is returned as `NULL`, but it should comes with id value in xml

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `/*` characters at the end of your last line, like this:

```
@dataxml.nodes('/Parentnode/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@childnode")]') AS XD(t)
```

*Also I had to remove the `$` character at the end of the `FROM` keyword, but I'm guessing that could just be a typo. I tested this is SQL Server 2012.*